# In the Dresdenverse, which vampires have souls?

Tags: the-dresden-files

There are four groups of vampires named in the Dresdenverse:

1. White Court: they clearly have souls, they're basically humans possessed by a demon
2. Red Court: unknown
3. Black Court: fairly sure they are soulless
4. Jade Court: unknown, only mentioned once

I can't decide about the Red Court – I suspect they might have souls, but there is one reference to what happens if the Reds were to turn a wizard (e.g., Harry), they would have access to all of that wizard's abilities and knowledge. But why? If the person still had a soul, presumably they could resist/fight. It's possible they meant by using torture, but that wouldn't require turning them into a vampire, nor would it really get the *full* use of their abilities. (Assuming full Red Court, not the pre-feeding ones, obviously they still have souls). It could also be the Red King had enough mind-control of them, to make them "willing" allies, not sure.

And I haven't read anything in-series about the Jade Court, other than their being one-time allies of the White Council, which is hard to deduce much from.

Comment: @Radhil, yes, I meant pre-feeding version by "half-turned", I can correct that. But do you have any evidence they became soulless after that? Obviously they physically transformed, but was that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dresden discusses who has souls and who doesn't several times in the context of soulgazes. We have on-page proof that Red Court vamps can't be soulgazed and that White Court vamps can be. I assume that Black Court cannot be as they're essentially dead, but can't find a direct reference in the texts I have digitally. Jade Court is mysterious and unknown.

Outside of vampires, Fae and Demons do not have souls. Werewolves and fallen-angel possessed humans do. Wolf-weres do not.

**Bianca is Red Court and soulless**

> I ignored it, meeting Bianca’s gaze as I came level with her. Vampires
>   don’t have souls. She didn’t have to fear my gaze.

*Butcher, Jim. Grave Peril (The Dresden Files, Book 3) (p. 309). Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

Chalk up the blanket statement that Vampires don't have souls to an overgeneralization by an unreliable narrator, because White Court vamps do appear to have souls:

**Thomas is White Court and ensouled**

> It was only the second time I’d ever seen a soulgaze happen to someone
>   else. There was an instant where both of them locked their eyes on
>   each other’s. Molly’s eyes widened suddenly, like a frightened doe’s,
>   and she jerked in a sharp breath. She stared at him with her chin
>   twisting to one side, as if she were trying—and failing—to look away.
>   Thomas went unnaturally still, and though his eyes also widened, it
>   reminded me more of a cat crouching down in anticipation, just before
>   pouncing on its prey. Molly’s back arched slightly and a soft moan
>   escaped her. Her eyes filled with tears. “God,” she said. “God. No.
>   No, you’re beautiful. God, you hurt so much, need so much. . . . Let
>   me help you. . . .” She fumbled for his hand.
>
> …
>
> “What just happened?” “You soulgazed Thomas. You both lost
>   perspective. He nearly ate you.”

*Butcher, Jim. Changes (The Dresden Files, Book 12) (p. 258). Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

**Mavra is Black Court and unclear** The state of her soul isn't explicitly stated, but she's dead. I can read this as either Harry avoiding her eyes to avoid a horrific soulgaze or to avoid vampiric powers.

> Her dead man’s eyes looked down at me, and I had an abrupt
>   understanding of why Michael had called her “it.” Mavra wasn’t a woman
>   anymore. Whatever she was, she wasn’t a person. Not like I understood
>   people, in any case. Those eyes pulled at mine, pulled at me with a
>   kind of horrid fascination, the same sickly attraction that makes you
>   want to see what’s under the blanket in the morgue, to turn over the
>   dead animal and see the corruption beneath. I fought and kept my eyes
>   away from hers. “Come, wizard,” Mavra whispered, her face utterly
>   without expression. “Let us test one another, thou and I.” I

*Butcher, Jim. The Dresden Files Collection 1-6 (The Dresden Files Box-Set) . Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

**Non Vampires**

> There were only two kinds of people whose eyes I could meet for more
>   than a second or two: the people who had already met my eyes in a
>   soulgaze were one kind; inhuman beings from the Nevernever were the
>   other.

*Butcher, Jim. The Dresden Files Collection 1-6 (The Dresden Files Box-Set) . Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

> the fae have no souls to gaze

*Butcher, Jim. The Dresden Files Collection 1-6 (The Dresden Files Box-Set) . Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

> Demons, however, are a different matter. Demons aren’t people. They
>   don’t have the problem of having a soul, and they don’t worry about
>   silly things like good and evil, or right and wrong.

*Butcher, Jim. The Dresden Files Collection 1-6 (The Dresden Files Box-Set) . Penguin Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.*

Comment: Apparently we can add Kraken to the list, after Harry soul-gazed one in Battle Grounds.

Answer (score 2):

The soul issue is a matter of opinion and would require defining what a soul is in the Dresden verse among other things to answer

I will address the implied question about the Red Court

Having a soul does not make one selfless being turned means your former allies will try their best to kill you, perhaps a few individuals would allow themselves to die rather than become a monster but only a few, most would join their new faction wholeheartedly.